# Where to create jni folder in Android Studio

Tags: java-native-interface, android-studio

In Eclipse I create jni folder at the root of the project when I need to create native android methods. Where should I create this folder in Android Studio project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure of the project should be the same, so I'd put it in the same place.

That being said, Android Studio doesn't have a C/C++ features, at least not yet (because IDEA doesn't have it but there is huge demand for it and they are working it). Intellij is currently referring all NDK related questions back to Google at the moment.

Basically what I think you'd have to do is make a Build task inside of Android Studio to call the ndk-build.cmd (or some external task) yourself which isnt horrible, but there's not going to be a nice configuration screen to do it. If I'm not making sense, respond to this and I'll post a screen shot of what I'm talking about.