# Where to place JNI/native libraries in Android Studio Project

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to compile the following code:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master

into an apk file.

To do this,
I created a default Android project with an empty activity. Afterwards, I added the relevant java files from the repository to my project and made some modifications. I also added the appropriate xml/image resources to my project.

Now, I need to add the JNI/native libraries to my project. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master/native/

However, I don't know where to place them. The only references I could find were

1] [How to add JNI Libraries in android studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256566/how-to-add-jni-libraries-in-android-studio-project) But, my project structure looks different from  the screenshot.

and

2] [Where to create jni folder in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602734/where-to-create-jni-folder-in-android-studio) which is old/outdated/lacks detail.

Here is my project structure:

[image: Project_Structure]

Comment: Just making sure you looked at: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/build

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The typical structure of an Android project with jni support is as below:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt // Your cmake configuration files. 
├── app.iml
├── build
├── build.gradle
├── libs
├── proguard-rules.pro
└── src
    ├── androidTest
    │   └── java
    ├── main
    │   ├── AndroidManifest.xml
    │   ├── cpp // Directory to put your jni native source code. 
    │   │   └── native-lib.cpp
    │   ├── java
    │   ├── jniLibs // Directory to put your jni libs, i.e. the .so files. 
    │   └── res
    └── test
        └── java
```

But, theoretically you can configure your `jniLibs` path anywhere that you like inside the **app** level `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
            }
        }
    }
    ...
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            // put your jni libs.
            jniLibs.srcDirs += "${projectDir}/jniLibs"]
        }
        debug {
            // put your debug version jni libs.
            jniLibs.srcDirs += "${projectDir}/jniLibs/debug"]
        }
        release {
            // put your release version jni libs.
            jniLibs.srcDirs += "${projectDir}/jniLibs/release"]
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

---

For Android Studio 3.0+, you don't need to explicitly configure the `jniLibs` path for your `c/c++` source code as it will be automatically managed by Android Studio. All those `c/c++` source code under `src/main/cpp` will be compiled and packaged into your apk automatically.

Comment: i have .so file of other app that i have decompile
i don't have native-lib.cpp file of that .so means i don't have native code i only have  .so
can i integrate and run it in my project because when i m runing the project this error
is coming
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.krunal.camarademo.Libs.nativesystem.DMDHDR.getBracketedCount() (tried Java_com_krunal_camarademo_Libs_nativesystem_DMDHDR_getBracketedCount and Java_com_krunal_camarademo_Libs_nativesystem_DMDHDR_getBracketedCount__)