# I want to use different library in debug and release mode In Android

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin

debug:

```
jniLibs/armeabi/a.so
```

release:

```
jniLibs/armeabi/b.so
```

I want to use a.so in debug mode and `b.so` in release mode, how can I do in `build.gradle` or other?

The `.so` library is third library, placed in `jniLibs/armeabi/`. I don't know the specific call timing, so I cannot use `System.loadLibrary()` method.

Thanks!

Comment: do you use this System.loadLibrary() to load your SO files?

Comment: if yes, check my answer.

Comment: @user1506104 The so library is third library, placed in jniLibs/armeabi/. I don't know the specific call timing, so I cannot use System.loadLibrary method.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52048933/8034839 for alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historically the NDK supported ARMv5 (`armeabi`), and 32-bit and 64-bit `MIPS`, but ***support for these ABIs was removed in NDK r17***.

Also, note below anouncement from Google:

> Starting August 1, 2019, your apps published on Google Play will need to support 64-bit architectures. 64-bit CPUs deliver faster, richer experiences for your users. Adding a 64-bit version of your app provides performance improvements, makes way for future innovation, and sets you up for devices with 64-bit-only hardware.

So, you should stop using the legacy `armeabi` for your Android applications. And, start to use the 64-bit ABIs.
See https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit 
 and https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis for more details.

For how to organise the **debug** and **release** build type, theoretically, you can put the `mynative-lib.so` anywhere you like, e.g. they are under `/Users/<your-usr-name>/android/jniLibs`. But, I would like recommend you to arrange your **debug** and **release** build types as below (***per each supported ABI***):

```
jniLibs
├── debug
│    ├── arm64-v8a
│    │   └── mynative-lib.so
│    ├── armeabi-v7a
│    │   └── mynative-lib.so
│    ├── x86
│    │   └── mynative-lib.so
│    └── x86_64
│        └── mynative-lib.so
└── release
     ├── arm64-v8a
     │   └── mynative-lib.so
     ├── armeabi-v7a
     │   └── mynative-lib.so
     ├── x86
     │   └── mynative-lib.so
     └── x86_64
         └── mynative-lib.so
```

Then configure your `app/build.gradle` file for it to point to the correct build types, i.e.

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            // put your jni libs that do not distinguish debug and release.
            jniLibs.srcDirs += "/Users/<your-usr-name>/android/jniLibs"]
        }
        debug {
            // put your debug version jni libs.
            jniLibs.srcDirs += "/Users/<your-usr-name>/android/jniLibs/debug"]
        }
        release {
            // put your release version jni libs.
            jniLibs.srcDirs += "/Users/<your-usr-name>/android/jniLibs/release"]
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**NOTE**: Replace `/Users/<your-usr-name>/android/jniLibs` with your own correct path.

Comment: Great well! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another alternative. Add your debug SO file like so:

```
app/src/debug/jniLibs/armeabi/<yourdebug>.so
```

Retain your release SO file in the main sourceset like so:

```
app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/<yourrelease>.so
```

It is important that `<yourdebug>.so` and `<yourrelease>.so` have the same filename for this to work.

Cheers!

Comment: This deserves all the upvotes! This seems to be the default expected path as well, no need to modify paths in the build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `System.loadLibrary()` to load your SO files, do this:

```
public final static boolean IS_DEBUG = BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase("debug");

static {
    if(IS_DEBUG) {
        System.loadLibrary("yourdebugso");
    }
    else {
        System.loadLibrary("yourreleaseso");
    }
}
```

Comment: The so library is third library, placed in jniLibs/armeabi/. I don't know the specific call timing, so I cannot use System.loadLibrary method.

Comment: I added an alternative answer. I am not removing this original answer as this is another way to load different SO depending on build type.